# How to i automate a test that targets values that change from one test to another?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, web-testing

Currently I am testing an online shop. I want to automate the checkout process but each time an item has been added to the cart and the checkout process is completed that particular item is removed from the list, and the second time the test runs, it returns an error because it can not find the item.

Is there any way I can build a test that completes the test without failing because it can not find that particular item ?

I am using Selenium with PHP and Selenium IDE.
Please note that I am just a beginner in automation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,
Radu

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the test you do, you should be very confident with the expected initial situation of your system under test when the test starts. In your case, if your test needs a specific item to be available, then this should be part of your "test setup" section.

Let's say you have 100 tests that needs an item to be available. 
I can see 2 different strategies to solve your issue:

1. At the beginning of your test suite, deploy a custom brand new web site with your 100 products available. Your tests will update/destroy those data but you don't case because next time you run the test, you will deploy a brand new set of items.
2. At the end of each test case, you do a custom-action that will clean your system by adding the item back in the shop.